# Rails 4 Select Tag - Prompt Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I want to add a blank prompt message for my drop down `Select Gender` and allow the previous value from the database to be selected if one is selected and stored.

```
<%= f.select :gender, "<option value='1'>Male</option><option value='2'>Female</option>".html_safe, prompt: "Select Gender" %>
```

With the above code the prompt message doest seem to get added. When i try `include_blank` it adds a blank value but doesn't use the prompt text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.select(:gender, options_for_select([['Male', 1],['Female', 2]],@user.gender), {:include_blank => 'Select Gender'}, { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

Comment: what is prompt option used for? isnt that supposed to set the blank value?

Comment: prompt and include_blank both does the same work the only difference is that if the value is already set prompt will not render blank value . So you don't have to pass the selected value in options_for_select hash.

Comment: So you can write your select helper like  <%= f.select(:gender, options_for_select([['Male', 1],['Female', 2]]), {:prompt => 'Select Gender'}, { :class => 'form-control' }) %>